# Why does Path=SelectedItem.Content work for ComboBox in WPF but not Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, combobox, selecteditem

The following code works fine in **WPF**.

In **Silverlight** it gives me the error **Invalid attribute value {Binding ElementName=WhichNumber, Path=SelectedItem.Content} for property Text. **

How can I get this to work in **Silverlight**?

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="WhichNumber" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="One"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Two"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Three"/>
    </ComboBox>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=WhichNumber, Path=SelectedItem.Content}"/>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Silverlight 2 or Silverlight 3 (which has element-to-element binding)?

Comment: in 2, oh that's good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't support Relative Binding (binding the attribute of one element to the value of another element's attribute value) while WPF has full support for that kind of binding.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could move to Silverlight 3 which introduces UI element to element binding :)

For some reason (why they did this is beyond me), the syntax is slightly different, instead of writing when using WPF:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=WhichNumber, Path=SelectedItem.Content}"/>
```

you would write with Silverlight 3:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=WhichNumber, SelectedItem.Content}"/>
```

so without the 'Path=' part.

Unfortunately the Silverlight people at Microsoft have a tendency to make small changes to syntax and other things, rather than striving for easy code reuse across WPF and Silverlight.

Comment: You can actually use the 'Path=' part in Silverlight as well if you want.